# References about 3-manifolds

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

I am working on a subject of geometric group theory closely related to 3-manifolds, and in order to understand these links, I am seeking a good reference about 3-manifolds, as self-contained as possible, and dealing with: loop and sphere theorems, Heegaard diagrams, Haken manifolds.

I browsed Hempel's book, *[3-manifolds](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=chel-349.h)*, but a lot of PL topology seems to be assumed.

**EDIT:** I asked the same question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160323/references-about-3-manifolds).

Comment: perhaps it might help [ http://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/cucei-maths/elementary-3-manifolds/ ] and [ http://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/cucei-maths/elementary-3-manifolds/referencias-para-tres-variedad/ ]

Comment: My feeling is that basic PL topology (simplicial complex, simplicial maps, regular neighborhoods) will be assumed by any book on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to read Hatcher's [book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/3M/3Mdownloads.html). It does not require a lot of background and covered a lot basic material. However, I do not know if Heegard diagrams and Haken manifolds is covered there as I never finished reading it. Real experts in the forum should be able to give better recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the beautifully illustrated N. Saveliev's *Lectures on the topology of 3-manifolds*.

Comment: take a look [ http://books.google.com.mx/books?id=fqexbFMISJ8C&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=3+manifolds+Fomenko&source=bl&ots=ggOWqu13fS&sig=ZEfc1xHcwf0hkjt_8SmoHNANSAs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t9ATU79Rpe7ZBaLFgHg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=3%20manifolds%20Fomenko&f=false ]